# Take diff of two vertical opened windows in Vim

Tags: vim, diff, vimdiff

I've have two files opened. They are opened in vertical mode, next to next. Can I instantly diff these two files without leaving or closing Vim ?

Answer (score 200, accepted):

To begin diffing on all visible windows:

```
:windo diffthis
```

which executes `:diffthis` on each window.

To end diff mode:

```
:diffoff!
```

(The `!` makes `diffoff` apply to all windows of the current tab - it'd be nice if `diffthis` had the same feature, but it doesn't.)

Comment: The `:windo` command makes it even better. Thanks. I'll will map it to make it easier.

Comment: That's good answer, but note that minibufexplorer window should be closed before this operation, if opened. Otherwise diff shows incorrect    results.

Comment: One can use an alias`:windo difft[this]`. Ref: `:help diff`

Answer (score 28):

in each of the windows you want to diff type:

```
:diffthis
```

If you want to diff all of the open windows, you can do:

```
:windo diffthis
```

(`windo` will apply the command to all open windows)

Answer (score 11):

Following up on the earlier answers,

- `:windo difft` (short for `diffthis`) will start diff mode in all the open windows.
- `:windo diffo` (short for `diffoff`) will stop diff mode in all the open windows.

I have the following mappings in my `vimrc` to make it easier:

```
command! Difft windo diffthis
command! Diffo windo diffoff
```

Answer (score 6):

Following on the earlier answers I adapted the mapping provided by @cxw. The following mapping automatically closes **NERDTree** and diffs the open windows. It does not matter if **NERDTree** is closed, it works the same way. I do this quite often so it saved me quite some time.

```
command! Difft NERDTreeClose | windo diffthis
```